# VSTO Outlool AddIn. How to send custom field with AppointmentItem to another Outlook user?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, icalendar

I developed a Outlook Addin (VSTO) for Appointments. My Addin adds some custom info to Appointments. What I want to achieve is that another Outlook user (having my AddIN installed) can work with this custom info. Therefore I somehow want to set a UserProperty on Outlook's ApppointmentItem of User A. THen User A sends the invitation for this appointment via Email and on Outlook of User B this UserProperty is accessible by the Addin in Outlook of User B.

One question in this regard is what standard does Exchange / Outlook use/support to send invitations?
My assumption: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546 (From Outlook2007 onward)

So what do I need to do that UserProperties are added to the iCalendar invitation? How do I extract them on the other side (Outlook of User B?)
What events should I listen to for
a) the moment of sending the invitation at Outlook of User A?
b) the moment of receiving the invitation at Outlook of User B?

Or is my concept complete rubbish and there is another solution to this?

Hannes

Answer (score 0):

If you set named properties, Outlook will try to preserve them by sending the message in the TNEF format. Be aware, you need to set a user property on the outgoing items, not the appointment item created on your calendar. You may find the [How To: Add a custom property to the UserProperties collection of an Outlook e-mail item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/19/how-to-add-a-custom-property-to-the-userproperties-collection-of-an-e-mail-item-in-outlook/) article helpful.

But I'd suggest creating online centralized storage (for example, a web service) where you may put the data and request it on the recipient side back. There are a lot of cases when your data can be vanished.

Comment: i already created an online storage, but i somehow need to transfer the correct id within the web service from user a to user b . thanks for the tip!